# Play ENTITY keep case sensitive table name (postgres)

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework, ebean

I need to keep case sensitive my table name in postgresql.
Indeed when i annotate 
@Table(name="SiteType")
public class SiteType extends Model

My table name will be "sitetype".
I try to add 
@Table(name="`SiteType`")

But eovlution default script will generate the following script problem :
constraint pk_"SiteType" primary key (id))

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Postgres supports mixed-case tablenames (and column names)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive) but this is strongly discouraged. I'm not sure offhand how to get Ebean to go along with non-standard tablenames like this. May I ask why this is important?

Comment: Because i need to retrieve my class name : SiteType from my table name.

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Because i need to do                     aClass = Class.forName(TABLENAME);

Comment: Your usecase still seems dubious to me, but in that case I would suggest converting camelcase classname FooBarBaz into table name foo_bar_baz and doing that trivial conversion back and forth. So given table name `site_type` you know you're looking for class `SiteType`.